# MongoDB connection error : Oracle goldengate mongodb change data capture setup

Tags: mongodb, change-data-capture, oracle-golden-gate

While connecting to mongodb from goldengate big data(19c classic) GGSCI interface. I'm facing below error

GGSCI (meteor-VirtualBox) 1> alter credentialstore add user mongodb://@meteor.rjzzi46.mongodb.net/admin password  alias mongo

Error: Unable to open credential store.

GGSCI (meteor-VirtualBox) 2

#goldengate#mongodb#oraclegoldengate#goldengatebigdata

I just followed the official documentation;
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/big-data/21.1/gadbd/using-oracle-goldengate-capture-mongodb.html#GUID-AE0E4A74-5604-4C6D-9887-204867AD519B